# How can I know, an allocated space is successfully freed?

Tags: c, memory

Does anyone know, how can we verify whether an allocated space is successfully freed? In the manual page, it says that "free() returns no value".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three possible cases:

```
free( NULL );     // does nothing, so always works
free( malloc(42) );  // does something, always works
free( 666 );      // undefined behaviour - returned value would be meaningless
```

So there is no case where testing `free()` has a point.

Comment: to conclud: if free() works, it returns nothing and if not, the program crashes. So it's always too late to verify the failure of free, and that's why we don't do it. Is that right?

Comment: @alwin Well, the program may not crash - that's the wonder of undefined behaviour - but basically, yes.

Comment: If your program is correct, `free` always works. The only time it might do "something else" (like crashing) is if you've invoked UB. A correct program never does anything that might invoke UB.

Comment: @R.. Excuse me, what does UB mean here?

Comment: @alwinlin UB == undefined behaviour

Answer (score 10):

There is no return value because there is no failure case. `free` always succeeds. There is nothing to check.

Note that this assumes you are using it correctly. If you pass to `free` a pointer which is not valid as an argument to `free`, for example an uninitialized pointer, a pointer to an already-freed object, or a pointer to an object not obtained by `malloc`, then your program has **undefined behavior**. This is not a reportable error; rather it means **anything could happen**.

Answer (score 1):

A "wrong" free will crash your application, so there's no need to make sure it works :)

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 10);
    free(a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

> $ ./example 
>   *** glibc detected**  ./example: double free or corruption (fasttop):
>   0x08a3e008 **
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x17c501]

Comment: That's if you're really lucky. A less fortunate outcome would be that your program executes arbitrary code from the file it's using as input.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify the inner workings of the heap allocator, I don't think of a standard way to do it.

If you want to make sure that the memory is re-initialized, I suggest you zero the memory yourself before freeing. I don't recall any guarantee of the `free` function to zero the memory.

Comment: It would be pointless for `free` to zero the memory, because after the `free` it's illegal to read bytes from that memory.

Comment: `free` can do this, if it does it before freeing the memory.

Comment: Eli: I guess the point was that since after `free()` nothing can access the memory anymore anyway why bother writing stuff there that can never be read again?

Comment: This is true if the CPU and OS give you that ability. In many (embedded mostly) systems this is not always true, and you can access (read, at the very least) data from the heap even if it was freed already.